# Overload type hint with Literal and Enum not working in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I want to typehint an overload function. For that I use the `overload` decorator from `typing`. I want to set multiple possible callees based on a parameter's value. This parameter is `color`.

I have this code:

```py
from typing import Literal, overload
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 0
    BLUE = 1
    GREEN = 2

@overload
def func(
    *,
    title: str,
    color: Literal[Color.RED, Color.BLUE],
    description: str,
) -> None:
    ...

@overload
def func(
    *,
    title: str,
    color: Literal[Color.GREEN],
) -> None:
    ...

def func(
    *,
    title: str = None,
    color: Color = None,
    description: str = None,
) -> None:
    print(title, color, description)


func(title="hello", color=Color.GREEN, description="hello")
```

I want to get a warning when I try to set the `description`, even the `color` is set to `Color.GREEN`, but I don't get a warning:

[image: no_warning_enum]

When I do the same just with strings, it works. I replaced the Literals with `Literal["red", "blue"]` and `Literal["green"]` and changed the type of `color` to `str`:

[image: warning_strings]

Accordingly, there is no error, when I don't try to set `description`, which I expect:

[image: no_warnings_strings]

Python Version: 3.8 
IDE: PyCharm

Comment: The elements of an `Enum` are not literals; it's not clear what `Literal` should do with them, but I suspect whatever it *does* do can only be considered undefined behavior.

Comment: `"green"`, `"red"`, and `"blue"` *are* literals.

Comment: @chepner Is there a workaround?

Comment: @chepner that's wrong, `Literal` supports Enum values (as per [PEP586](https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/#legal-parameters-for-literal-at-type-check-time)), and `mypy` allows that; also all invalid `Literal` items are marked as error by typecheckers (try in playground `Literal[Color.RED]` and `Literal[1+2]` - the latter will cause a `mypy` error). Moreover, the question is clearly about `pycharm` bug, and `mypy` is correctly angry [on that line](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=cb8e7b021b8334c80a12150900157e6b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You discovered a `pycharm` bug, here's the [corresponding issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42473). There is no workaround suggested, and I doubt there can be one.

`mypy` handles such overload case properly, also pointing out missing `| None` in the implementation signature (`title: str = None` is usually a bad thing to write, explicit is better than implicit, and `mypy` has hidden the decision to infer such type implicitly under a configuration flag for this reason - such thing was enabled by default earlier). Here's a [playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=cb8e7b021b8334c80a12150900157e6b) to check.

To fix the implicit-optional issue mentioned above, you could do the following (`Optional[X]` is equivalent to `Union[X, None]`, where `X` is some valid type):

```py
from typing import Optional
...
# Overloads here

def func(
    *,
    title: Optional[str] = None,
    color: Optional[Color] = None,
    description: Optional[str] = None,
) -> None:
    print(title, color, description)
```

or, on python 3.10 and higher or with `annotations` future-import,

```py
...
# Overloads here

def func(
    *,
    title: str | None = None,
    color: Color | None = None,
    description: str | None = None,
) -> None:
    print(title, color, description)
```

Finally, as long as you always require `title` and `color` in both overloads, why not make them required in implementation (note that first two args don't have to be Optional any more)?

```py
from typing import Optional
...
# Overloads here

def func(
    *,
    title: str,
    color: Color,
    description: Optional[str] = None,
) -> None:
    print(title, color, description)
```

Your usage is absolutely valid, and it's just a bug in your IDE.

Comment: Forgot to mention, that I'm using Python 3.8, so `str | None` doesn't work.

Comment: @puncher Then `Union[str, None]` or `Optional[str]` can be used instead.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Could you add that to the answer too

Comment: There is still a question I have. If PyCharm can't display it, what's the purpose then. I mean you're making those type hints to avoid passing wrong values to prevent bugs.

Comment: Hm, I don't use pycharm or vscode, but use type hints extensively - usually with `mypy`. Type checking is not the same as IDE hints/linting, it's more about code quality, and usually is coupled with CI pipeline that runs a type checker against the codebase. And such CI pipeline would reveal the issue you have (and show an error at the line with an invalid call), even if PyCharm doesn't notice it. Anyway people can't open all files and check that there are no errors highlighted - there are better tools for that.

Comment: And the bug will be fixed eventually, I guess, so in future it will work in pycharm too.